# Segwit2x mining after the fork

Tags: mining-pools

When will we be able to start mining Segwit2x?
I am currently mining with Slush's Pool. Will the entire pool switch or should I switch to a different pool?
Is there anything I should do on my side?

Answer (score -3):

You can start mining on Segwit2x official pool

http://pool.b2x-segwit.io

Best regards.

Comment: This has nothing to do with the SegWit2X referred to in OP's question.